# Android Emulator Doesn't Start | Throws Error "An undetermined error occurred inside the DirectSound subsystem"

Tags: windows, windows-10, android-studio, emulator

I'm trying to get Android Emulator started on Android Studio. When I run the emulator, the Android loading screen (*Android* on a black background) appears and keeps loading.

I'm using AMD Ryzen 3400G without a discreet graphics card. I have enabled *Hyper-V* and am using an arm64-v8a Nougat image for the Virtual Device.

I'm getting these errors:

```
21:53   Emulator: dsound: Could not initialize ADC
21:53   Emulator: dsound: Could not create capture buffer
21:53   Emulator: dsound: Reason: An undetermined error occurred inside the DirectSound subsystem
21:53   Emulator: dsound: Could not initialize ADC
21:53   Emulator: dsound: Could not create capture buffer
21:53   Emulator: dsound: Reason: An undetermined error occurred inside the DirectSound subsystem
21:53   Emulator: aud
21:53   Emulator: io: Failed to create voice `goldfish_audio_in'
21:53   Emulator: C:\Users\Nitin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-aarch64.exe: warning: opening audio input failed
```

As this seems to be a problem with audio input and I do not have a microphone. I enabled the *Stereo Mix (Realtek High Definition Audio)* in input settings, but that didn't help.

I am not able to figure out what is messing with the Emulator.

Comment: Do you still have the problem? I satrted to have the problem when I upgraded to Andriod Studio 3.6.1

Comment: Probable duplicate. For a solution see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53651779/error-launching-the-android-project-on-emulatorapi-28-on-windows

Answer (score 1):

It's because of the Windows 10 Privacy settings.

To Fix: Click Start, go to ⚙ Settings> Privacy Settings> Microphone. Turn On "Allow apps to access your microphone"

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53970025/11075282)